# Quartz.NET: triggers aren't getting triggered, nothing getting logged

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

As the title says, I can't get Quartz.NET to work at all. I've got the latest versions of Quartz.NET (2.2.1), common.logging (2.1.2), common.logging.nlog (2.0.0), and NLog (2.1.0) from NuGet. Triggers aren't firing and there's absolutely nothing getting logged by Quartz. I'm guessing I screwed up the config somehow.

My App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ...

    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog">
        <arg key="configType" value="FILE" />
        <arg key="configFile" value="~/NLog.config" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>

  <quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ServerScheduler" />

    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />

    <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
  </quartz>

...

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
...
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.2.0" newVersion="2.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

There's one job and one trigger associated with it:

```
{Trigger 'DEFAULT.DailyYahooUpdateTrigger':  triggerClass: 'Quartz.Impl.Triggers.CronTriggerImpl calendar: '' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: 01/29/2014 18:38:00 +00:00}
    [Quartz.Impl.Triggers.CronTriggerImpl]: {Trigger 'DEFAULT.DailyYahooUpdateTrigger':  triggerClass: 'Quartz.Impl.Triggers.CronTriggerImpl calendar: '' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: 01/29/2014 18:38:00 +00:00}
    CalendarName: null
    Description: null
    EndTimeUtc: null
    FinalFireTimeUtc: null
    HasMillisecondPrecision: false
    JobDataMap: {Quartz.JobDataMap}
    JobKey: {DEFAULT.DailyYahooUpdate}
    Key: {DEFAULT.DailyYahooUpdateTrigger}
    MisfireInstruction: 0
    Priority: 5
    StartTimeUtc: {29/1/2014 18:37:44 +00:00}
```

The scheduler is started, the job and trigger are added properly, and logging works otherwise. The nextFireTime comes and goes and nothing happens.

The trigger creation code:

```
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
        .Create()
        .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(jobDetails.Time.Hours, jobDetails.Time.Minutes))
        .StartNow()
        .WithIdentity(jobDetails.Name + "Trigger")
        .Build();
```

Comment: How do you create your trigger and could you show us the cron expression ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that creates the trigger.

Comment: Need more code to reproduce the issue: jobDetails declaration (where does it come from) and how you are adding the job/trigger pair to the scheduler.

Comment: For some reason using DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder instead of CronScheduleBuilder made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your infos it should work; it should run once a day.

Make sure you have installed Common Logging NLog20]:

```
Install-Package Common.Logging.NLog20
```

And change this section:

```
  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog20">
        <arg key="configType" value="FILE" />
        <arg key="configFile" value="~/NLog.config" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
```

and this should be your runtime section:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

You can check the schedule of your trigger with this:

```
private static void GetNext10FireTimes(ITrigger trigger)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List of next 10 schedules: ");

    var dt = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    if (dt == null)
        break;

    Console.WriteLine(dt.Value.ToLocalTime());

    dt = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(dt);
    }
}
```

A full, working example can be found [here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=669adf1af64df389&id=669ADF1AF64DF389!244&authkey=!) (**QuartzNetDailyAtHourAndMinute.zip**).

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your issue, and this has worked for me:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(jobDetails.Time.Hours, jobDetails.Time.Minutes))
    .WithIdentity(jobDetails.Name + "Trigger")
    .Build();
```

Remove the `.StartNow()` and the trigger should fire.

Hope it helps!